# BizTalk AS2 receive port generating extra MDN

Tags: biztalk, actionscript-2

I am trying to receive an EDI message over AS2 from a partner. However partner is receiving two MDNs. One is postive MDN and that is fine. **We are sending asynchronous MDN**
Problem is they are receiving another unknown/unwanted/bad MDN along with postive MDN, and that contains only this in the MDN content.

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2020 16:47:46 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It will be something in your set-up of the MDN generation... without seeing the configuration it is hard to say.  It is possible that the incoming message is meeting the criteria for another trading partner enough to generate the bad MDN so you may have to check other trading partners as well.  Check the raw content inbound and outbound to see what message properties are being matched etc.   That is the best I can say without seeing the set up.

Comment: We do not have any other partner configuration matching with the inbound message headers.
Also at sending partner end, it is showing "Unknown" sender, "Unknown" receiver and Processing status : "DONE With Errors", so not sure it matched any partner configuration.

Comment: I just found, it is not an MDN, it is response headers which IIS is sending. Do you know if there is any way to stop IIS from sending response headers?